# Tensorflow Object Detection : Bounding box doesn't overlay on image

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run Tensorflow's Object Detection example([object_detection_tutorial.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)) as it is. But, at the end of the complete Jupyter notebook execution I don't see the bounding box.

[image: Image with no bounding box]

I have followed instruction by running the following commands in the right paths-

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

And even the model builder test runs successfully-

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

I have verified that the model has successfully downloaded. And even the images are in the right paths.

I don't see any errors in the console as well. Please can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The current model listed by the master branch is unstable.

This is related to [tensorflow/models issue 2773](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2773) and there is a fix for it.
In the "Variables" section of models/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb you have to change the model.

Just replace the model name so the it looks like this

```
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
```

and you will happily detect dogs and people and kites in no time :)

Comment: I would really like to now if this fixed your problem dear @bozzmob .